# Create directories by reading file as a input in bash

Tags: bash, shell

i have a input file say temp.txt with content as following

```
  2013-08-13 /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-03-01
  2013-08-14 /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-03-02
  2013-08-15 /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-03-03
  2013-07-30 /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-07-30
  2013-07-31 /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-07-31
  2013-08-16 /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-08-13
```

I need to iterate over this file and create directories with the date specified at the begining of the line and then move the data in the directory specified after the date to this particular directory..

for example: for first line i need to do a

```
mkdir "2013-08-13"
```

and then

```
mv /data/PSG/LZ/INVENTORY_FORECAST/load_date=2013-03-01/  2013-08-13
```

i am trying to do it with

```
  cat temp.txt | while read line ; do  mkdir "echo $line | awk '{print $0}'"; done;
```

tried to use line as a array using

```
  cat temp.txt | while read line; do lineArray=($line) echo $line, ${lineArray[0]}, $lineArray[1];  done;
```

but none of these seem to work..  any idea about how to approach this problem ?

Comment: `echo "echo $line | awk '{print $0}'";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the lines into two variables. For example:

```
while read -r date path # reads the lines of temp.txt one by one, 
                        # and sets the first word to the variable "date", 
                        # and the remaining words to the variable "path"
do 
    mkdir -p -- "$date"  # creates a directory named "$date".
    mv -- "$path" "$date" # moves the file from the "$path" variable to the "$date folder"
done < temp.txt   # here we set the input of the while loop to the temp.txt file
```

The `--` option is used so that if a file starts with `-` it will not be interpreted as an option, but will be treated literally.

The `-p` or `--parents` makes the `mkdir` command to not trow an error if the directory exists, and to make parent directories if necessary.

Comment: You might want to use `mkdir -p` in case there are multiple identical dates.

Comment: Can you explain what each line of this script is doing? I have a similar issue, in that I want to use a "control" file as input to a bash script, and need to extract specific lines and turn them into variables

Comment: @JustinAmberson Added some explanations. Let me know if something is still unclear

Comment: nice, thank you for doing that. This pretty much means that a given input file has to have a uniform format for each line. Don't mean to bug you, but what if I want to process one "field" as a "string", is there a way to capture that with quotes or something?

Comment: @JustinAmberson Not sure I understand... If you want to read the whole line in to a variable you can do `while read -r var` with a singe variable after the read command.

Comment: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html The example "control" file has different items on each line. There are not line numbers present in a control file either. I want to do what this guy is doing but instead extract specific info from the file and assign it a variable, then move the input file somewhere based on the variable. I asked it here as well: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97679/automator-to-execute-shell-script-with-an-input-text-file-copy-it-to-specific-d

Comment: @JustinAmberson I think it would be better to ask a new question (on SO) with that, including the "control" file structure, which data you wan't to extract, what exactly you want to do with it. The comments are not very convenient for this, but post a link here and I will have a look at it in the morning

Comment: thanks for the offer! If I do make a new question I'll respond here. I'll probably fool around with it some on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
while read line
do
export dname=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
mkdir -p "$dname"
export fname=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
mv "$fname" "$dname"
done < temp.txt
```